# Post function running forever in JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a function setup to basically check if someone is signed in and if they are adding 1 to a variable. The problem is when run in an application such as a postman it lasts forever, and when to run in the browser it never goes to .then.

Html

```
$('.fa-regular.fa-heart').click(function(){
        $regular.toggleClass('hide');
        $solid.toggleClass('hide');
        $added.toggleClass('hide');
        $noadded.toggleClass('hide');
        console.log("running");
        fetch("/articles/popplus/<%= article.id%>", {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'default',
            body: JSON.stringify(null)
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log("data")
            console.log(data)
        });
    })
```

Node.js

```
router.post('/popplus/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  const user = await Users.findOne({ username: req.session.username })
  console.log(user)
  if (user){
    console.log(user.likedposts)
    if (!user.likedposts.includes(id)){
      console.log("here")
      req.article = await Article.findById(id)
      req.article.pop += 1
      let article = req.article
      user.likedposts.push(id)
      await user.save()
      await article.save()
      return "done"
    }
    else{
      console.log("already liked this post")
      return "already liked this post";
    }
  }
  else{
    console.log("sighn in");
    return {test: "must sighn in to like posts"};
  }
})
```

Comment: You're not meant to `return` a value from route handlers. You need to call `res.send()` or similar to send a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use res.send() instead of return becasue return is not used for event handlers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

To complete an Express request handler, you MUST send some sort of http response.  The usual way to do that is with `res.send(...)` or `res.json(...)`, but if you have no data to send, you can also just do `res.sendStatus(xxx)` or even just `res.end()`.

Express does not pay any attention to what you `return` from your request handler so returning a value from the request handler does nothing at all - it is entirely ignored.  Instead, you must explicitly call one of the above methods to send an http response.

If you don't send an http response by calling one of these type Express methods on the response object, then the client just sits there waiting for a response to come back to its request and it waits for awhile until eventually it times out the request.